# Uneditable Database Stored Locally within iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, xcode10

I am writing an exercise app using Swift / Xcode which includes an uneditable database of exercises that will be accessed constantly. This database is composed of arrays and simple exercise objects.  I would like to store this database within the app so it may be used offline and I can continue to use my current code, but I am open to other options.

Should I just create all 90 exercise objects and throw them in the same file as the database class?  I have heard of SQLite but I am not sure it is what I need.  What would be the simplest way to initialize the exercise objects and store them in the database?

Here is my [Exercise Class Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0D3x.png) , if it helps.

Comment: Store them as a text file inside your main bundle in json or plist format. Also post code as text and not as an image in your question.

Answer (score 0):

IMO using [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database) is by far the simplest solution to your problem. Since [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database) is an object store, you will simply store the objects directly in a so-called *Realm* - in your case an object of type `Exercise`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a good solution! I used [SwiftPlistManager](https://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/) and learned to keep all my info in a plist.  Thanks for the help!